# Button is creating error upon adding of image view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

Whenever I click the spin it generates this error and crashes the app. Before I upload the image view the app works fine and spin's great. I know the code is probably telling me head on whats wrong but I am having problems understanding this.

Stated below in bold is what its generating

```
- (IBAction)spinAction:(id)sender {

    [_chosenComponents removeAllObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < _componentsInPicker.count; i++) {
        int randNum = arc4random() % [self.theSlotPicker numberOfRowsInComponent:i];

        [_theSlotPicker selectRow:randNum inComponent: i animated:YES];
        [_chosenComponents addObject:
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:[(NSArray *)[_baseList objectAtIndex:i] indexOfObject:[(NSArray *)[_componentsInPicker objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:randNum]]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", _chosenComponents);
```

Spitting out after button is pressed/crash  "Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_1386_DIV,subcode=0x0)"

If you could please guide me on how to fix this error.

Thank you!

---

Output error: (lldb)

Comment: please post the error message that the app spits out to xcode's output window.

Comment: Putting \*\*<bold words>** inside a code block won't make them bold. Put the error separately so that others notice it.

Comment: Alright sorry about that newer to this. No such luck with below. Prior to adding the UIImageView it works like a charm.

Comment: @user2175105: try logging [self.theSlotPicker numberOfRowsInComponent:i]; inside the loop. Find out on which iteration it's happening. Also log , self.theSlotPicker and see if it's nil?

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring probably because there is a division by zero happening when you are using `arc4random() % .....`

Instead of using `arc4random() % n` use `arc4random_uniform(n)`. It will return a number in the range of 0 to n.

However this won't solve the inherent problem that

`[self.theSlotPicker numberOfRowsInComponent:i]` is returning zero at some point of time.